# Trouble adding computers to domain

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain-name

I work for a medical practice with three different facilities and our newest was previously an office set up almost identical to ours. With terminal services for remote access. Problem is their machines won't change domain names. I keep getting an error saying "The specified server cannot perform the requested action"

I have added all users at this location to our domain, they can log in remotely to an IP to get on the server, but locally need to be on with us as well. I've made sure TCP/IP settings are to obtain automatically and logged on "administrator" this computer.. HELP!

Thanks, and sorry XP for local machines and Server 2003 for remote.

Comment: I added some tags that I thought were appropriate, but you might want to tell the Windows guys here a bit more: what version Windows, do you use (I assumed so) Active Directory, etc.

Comment: Not exactly sure what your problem is here, but is the issue adding workstations to a domain?  Also logging on as an local administrator will not be sufficient rights to add a workstation to a domain.  You need domain credentials that have the right Add Workstations to domain.

Comment: This question isn't clear enough. Please clarify, are you trying to join workstations to a new domain? Are you simply trying to remote into a different domain? Did you change the domain of the terminal servers and now the workstations can't access it?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time problems with adding a computer to a domain can fall into these issues:

- Rights to add the computer to the
  domain
- DNS resolution (make sure the client computer can ping the Domain Controller)
- Firewall issues (this can be the case if the DC isn't local)
- Wanting to keep the same computer name

Try this:

1. Delete the computer account in ADUC (if one exists), and also on
   the client put the client computer into a generic "WORKGROUP".  Don't try and just change from one domain directly to the other.
2. Restart your workstation.
3. Do ipconfig/flushdns and ipconfig/registerdns in the
   workstation.
4. Rename the workstation to the name you want BUT leave it in the
   workgroup.
5. Restart the workstation again.
6. Now try to add the workstation to the domain with an account that has
   rights